# Foreign Key Error - ERROR 1005 (HY000) ... Can't create table ... `stored_on` (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm creating two tables in mariadb. The stored_on relation ties a shelf and a book together. Everything works fine except I added lib_floor to the stored on relation, and this error is suddenly appearing. When I remove lib_floor, the foreign key definition for lib_floor, and lib_floor from stored on primary key, there are no issues. Any ideas? The data type is the same (INT).

```
CREATE TABLE shelf (
    shelf_number        INT            NOT NULL,
    lib_name            VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    lib_floor           INT            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (lib_name) REFERENCES library (lib_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (shelf_number,lib_name,lib_floor)
);  

CREATE TABLE stored_on (    
    shelf_number      INT            NOT NULL,
    lib_name          VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    lib_floor         INT            NOT NULL,
    isbn              VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    total_copies      INT            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (shelf_number) REFERENCES shelf (shelf_number) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (lib_name) REFERENCES shelf (lib_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (lib_floor) REFERENCES shelf (lib_floor) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (isbn)  REFERENCES book (isbn) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (shelf_number,lib_name,lib_floor,isbn)
);
```

Warning 1:

> | Warning |  150 | Create  table ... .`stored_on` with
>   foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced
>   table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns near
>   'FOREIGN KEY (lib_floor) REFERENCES shelf (lib_floor) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE,
>       FOREIGN KEY (isbn)  REFERENCES book (isbn) ON DELETE CASCADE,
>       PRIMARY KEY (shelf_number,lib_name,lib_floor,isbn) )'. |

Error 1:

> | Error   | 1005 | Can't create table ...`stored_on` (errno:
>   150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Warning 2:

> Warning | 1215 | Cannot add foreign key constraint for
>   `stored_on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory, `shelf` needs to have an `INDEX` in which `lib_floor` is the first field mentioned. You can simply add an `INDEX` (it doesn't need to be `UNIQUE`):

```
CREATE TABLE shelf (
    shelf_number        INT            NOT NULL,
    lib_name            VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    lib_floor           INT            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (lib_name) REFERENCES library (lib_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (shelf_number,lib_name,lib_floor),
    INDEX (lib_floor)
);
```

Note that you would also get this error from `lib_name`, but the `FOREIGN KEY` declaration for `lib_name` in `shelf` automatically creates an index on it.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=90f381c42bc2dc94300bff871977c07f)

Comment: OH my gosh! Thank you so much. I'm in a database class, and we haven't needed index at all yet. I will read up on this and figure out its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are tricky.  There are several workarounds for err 150 (and others)

- Disable FKs, CREATE TABLEs, re-enable FKs
- Apply the FKs via ALTER after doing the relevant CREATE TABLEs
- (others?)